# Rack middleware fails to redirect on authentication in Sinatra

Tags: authentication, sinatra, rack, middleware

Why does the Rack middleware fail to redirect when coupled with default GET and POST login routes and 401 handling in the Sinatra app?

Relevant [Shield](https://github.com/cyx/shield) middleware extract  :

```
module Shield
  class Middleware
    attr :url

    def initialize(app, url = "/login")
      @app = app
      @url = url
    end

    def call(env)
      tuple = @app.call(env)

      if tuple[0] == 401
        [302, headers(env["SCRIPT_NAME"] + env["PATH_INFO"]), []]
      else
        tuple
      end
    end

  private
    def headers(path)
      { "Location" => "%s?return=%s" % [url, encode(path)],
        "Content-Type" => "text/html",
        "Content-Length" => "0"
      }
    end

    def encode(str)
      URI.encode_www_form_component(str)
    end
  end
end
```

View [full source code](https://github.com/cyx/shield/blob/master/lib/shield.rb) (104 lines/2.8kb).

Here a relevant extract of the Sinatra app:

```
# application_controller.rb
class ApplicationController < Sinatra::Base
  helpers Shield::Helpers
  use Shield::Middleware, "/login"
  ...

  get '/noway' do
    error(401) unless authenticated(User)
    erb :app_noway
  end  

  get '/login' do
    erb :login
  end

  post "/login" do
    if login(User, params[:login], params[:password])
      remember(authenticated(User)) if params[:remember_me]
      redirect(params[:return] || "/")          
    else
      redirect "/login"
    end
  end
end
```

Full source code (basic app displaying the problem behavior), for easy and immediate perusal: https://github.com/shieldtest/shieldtest

The repository is ready for a "clone and rackup" with database, env and all. Login credentials; email: shield@example.org, password: shield.

**Problem** 
When accessing a protected route (/noway), the middleware injects a authentication process, as intended. But after the successful autentication, the subsequent redirect always defaults to root, instead of the return URL for the protected page (/noway).

Solution needed
 The protected page (/noway) should be redirected to automatically after authenticating successfully via Shield.

---

**Visual walk-through**

**Step 1 (below)**: At the Sinatra main page. Click link to protected page (/noway)
[image]

**Step 2 (below)**: Redirected to /login correctly, as no user is authenticated. Enter correct login credentials correctly.
[image]

PROBLEM BEHAVIOR - redirected to main instead of the protected page
**Step 3A (below)**: After entering correct login credentials: sent back to main page (again)
[image]

TESTING LOGIN - protected page is accessible now (manually, by clicking page again)
**Step 4 (below)**: At the main page. Click the protected page (/noway) again => Access granted
[image]

Answer (score 0):

The `params[:return]`  was never forwarded to the POST request, it seems.

So, a 'dirty fix' would be to grab the return params and pass it via the login form to the POST request. This yields the desired behavior:

```
#login.rb
...
<% if params[:return] %>
  <input type='hidden' name='redirect' value="<%= params[:return] %>">
<% end %>
...
```

And then redirecting to the redirect params from the login form:

```
#application_controller.rb
post "/login" do
  if login(User, params[:login], params[:password])
    ...
    redirect to params[:redirect] || "/"
    ...
  end
end
```

Still, I would have preferred to understand why the middleware didn't perform as expected and how to fix/store this return params via the Rack middleware.